# Make IE in Windows 10 to have only 1 PID for all TABS

Tags: internet-explorer

In Windows 10, each IE tab has it's own PID. I need to suppress this to make IE have only 1 PID despite you open 10 different TABs. Currently if you open 10 TABs you see in Task manager 11 iexplore PIDs, which is not ok. Windows 7 had only one IE for all the tabs you might have open.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to disable LCIE(Loosely-Coupled IE) to disable multiple processes of IE:

1. Save below code as a **reg** file, then double click it to make it work in registry:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] 

   "TabProcGrowth"="0" 

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] 

   "TabProcGrowth"="0" 

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] 

   "TabProcGrowth"="0"
   ```
2. Restart IE then there will be only one iexplore process no matter how many tabs you open.